# Proof for number of rational ordered pairs on a line

Tags: analysis, rational-numbers

> It is given that the function $y=ax+b,\; a \neq 0$ has an ordered pair $(x,y)=( \sqrt{2}, 0)$. Prove that $y=ax+b$ does not have two or more rational ordered pairs.

From the above I know that  $-\frac ba= \sqrt2$.

Comment: Have you tried this at all? if it does, what can you say about the slope, $a$?

Comment: I suppose the slope can be positive or negative, as long as -b/a= \sqrt{2} holds.

And yes, I have tried. What makes you think I haven't?

Comment: Yes, but rather than positive or negative, can it be **rational**?

Comment: Yes, if b is irrational, a could be rational, like if b=-\sqrt{2}, a could be 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help on editing!

Comment: Onion, and if there are two ordered pairs which are rational, then what must the slope be?

Comment: Do you mean the slope must be rational? But is it right to assume it has two rational ordered pairs? Can't it just have one?

Comment: Onion, this is a proof by contradiction, allow me to spell it out more explicitly below

Comment: Sure I'd like to see! Many thanks Adam:)

Comment: You might have noticed that your post [received a close vote](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/353717) with the reason "This question is missing context or other details". To avoid having the post closed/downvoted, it is good to add some context (where the problem comes from), your own thoughts (what can you show and where you are stuck), etc. I have added at least what you have mentioned in the comments

Comment: Thank you Martin! I am quite new around and I am trying my best to adapt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that in fact there are two rational points $(q,r)$ and $(s,t)$. Then the slope of this line is just

$$a={t-r\over s-q}$$

which is also a rational. However, in that case

$$0=\sqrt 2\cdot a+b$$

so $b=-a\sqrt 2$

But then $r=aq-a\sqrt 2$ is what we conclude, and we know this is impossible, since $q-r/a=\sqrt 2$ would say $\sqrt 2$ is rational. We conclude that the two hypotheses "the line has two rational points" and "the point $(\sqrt 2,0)$ is on the line" are incompatible, and cannot both be true.

Comment: I'm lost at the point $$\sqrt{2}=0\cdot a+b$$ Shouldn't it be ( \sqrt{2}, 0)?

Comment: @Onion oops, got the point backwards. But it's fixed now

Comment: Well understood! Thank you very much for your help!!